# How do you select groups and all of their users where at least one user in the group has visited within the last X days in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get groups and all of their users where at least one user of the group has visited in at least 14 days then order by group_id, user_id. If a group only has users that are older than 14 days it should be ignored completely.

I'd also like to be able to count how many users each group has.

Basically, at least one user is keeping the entire group active by visiting within 14 days. If no one in the group has visited in that time, they are not displayed on the group page.

```
Group Table = groups
+----------+--------------+
| group_id |  group_name  |
+----------+--------------+
|        1 | first_group  |
|        2 | second_group |
|        3 | third_group  |
+----------+--------------+


User Table = users
+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| user_id | user_name | group_id |     last_visit      |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|       1 | user1     |        1 | 2017-01-01 12:00:00 |
|       2 | user2     |        3 | 2017-01-01 12:00:00 |
|       3 | user3     |        2 | 2017-01-11 12:00:00 |
|       4 | user4     |        1 | 2017-01-12 12:00:00 |
|       5 | user5     |        3 | 2017-01-12 12:00:00 |
|       6 | user6     |        3 | 2017-01-14 12:00:00 |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+


Desired Output if today's date is 2017-01-16 12:00:00
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| group_id | group_name  | user_id | user_name | user_count |     last_visit      |
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|        1 | first_group |       1 | user1     |          2 | 2017-01-01 12:00:00 |
|        1 | first_group |       4 | user4     |          2 | 2017-01-12 12:00:00 |
|        3 | third_group |       2 | user2     |          3 | 2017-01-01 12:00:00 |
|        3 | third_group |       5 | user5     |          3 | 2017-01-12 12:00:00 |
|        3 | third_group |       6 | user6     |          3 | 2017-01-14 12:00:00 |
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

What I have now. This gets users that have visited within the last 14 days but it ignores the rest in the group.

```
SELECT
users.user_id, users.user_name,
groups.group_id, groups.group_name
FROM users, groups
WHERE users.last_visit > NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
AND groups.group_id = users.group_id
ORDER BY groups.group_id, users.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes:

`sers.user_name` -> `users.user_name`

`group.group_id = users.user_id` -> `group.group_id = users.group_id`

```
SELECT
users.user_id, users.user_name,
groups.group_id, groups.group_name
FROM users, groups
WHERE users.last_visit > NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
ORDER BY users.group_id
```

select all users that have visited within the last 14 days ordered by users group ids.

also simply you can make foreach group_id make query to check if there is at least 1 user visit within last 14 days or not.

Comment: Typos are fixed now. Also, the statement you supplied gave me similar results as my original statement.

Comment: Then what is your problem?

Comment: Our statements do not produce the desired output. I am trying to get all of the users from groups where any user in the group has been active within the last 14 days along with member count of each eligible group. Our statements do not retrieve users in eligible groups that have not visited within 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use self joining it will work. I want to make some changing in your query

```
    SELECT
users.user_id,distinct(users.user_name),
groups.group_id, groups.group_name
FROM `users` 
left join `users` `group_users` on (`group_users`.`group_id` = `users`.`group_id`)
left join `groups` on (`users`.`group_id`=`groups`.`group_id`)
WHERE users.last_visit > NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
ORDER BY groups.group_id, users.user_id
```

i Hope it will surly help you thanks

Comment: This did not produce the desired output. I was getting fetch_assoc errors with the above statement. I have since resorted to using queries within a php while loop.